# REST GET semantics

Tags: api, rest, http

I am adding a GET endpoint to my service and I need to pass the caller's access token in the request. This is not a JWT which grants general access to the service, this is a token granting access to the resource that is being requested for. Can this still be a query parameter, my confusion is the query parameters are typically filters, but this is not.

`GET /chat-room/12345?access-token=<token>`

Any better suggestions?

The session token passed in header is not going to work.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't use the HTTP `Authorization` header? That's exactly what it's intended for.

Comment: This token is scoped to the short lived resource and user can be part of multiple such resources, so using one token that can be set in Authorization header is not going to work

Comment: _"Can this still be a query parameter, my confusion is the query parameters are typically filters"_ - yes it can, and services that use _signed requests_ often put the signature as a query-parameter. However a good reason for avoiding putting secrets or keys in the querystring is the increased risk of unintentional exposure (e.g.  in logfiles, error messages, etc) whereas the HTTP `Authorization` header is generally handled more sensitively by most software down-the-line).

Comment: This is not secret, this is just a uuid, to kind of optimize on recalculating user's access to the resource everytime a GET call is made. Backend will verify that uuid is issued to the caller.

Comment: If it's "not a secret" then don't call it an "access token".

Comment: yep, more like access-id, naming is hard :D

Comment: What your GET request do return?